# Eclipse plugin works when debugging but not when installing

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I wrote an Eclipse plugin that presents a right click menu option on any file or folder (for example, in navigator view). For each file selected (and for each file inside of a selected directory), the plugin computes and displays the MD5, SHA-1, SHA-256, SHA-384, or SHA-512 hash of the file. The plugin works perfectly when I debug while developing.

If I make the site using site.xml, put it on my server, and then install to Eclipse (it installs just fine), I see the menu. I can compute and display the hash for a selected file, but it just *won't work* for a selected folder. Absolutely nothing has changed in the code; it always works in debug mode, and it never works when I install it.

My question is this: how can I debug this? At first, I thought Eclipse's `workspace/.metadata/.log` file would offer some clue, but no error is output. I even went so far as to try adding some code in that writes a file to the desktop, but that file never gets created. Does anyone have any clue what is going on or how I should go about fixing this? I've never had such a hard time debugging before!

For reference, https://github.com/gfairchild/eclipse-hasher is the project. All source code is viewable there (it can be imported as an Eclipse project).

---

The answer ultimately involved 2 things:

1. I wasn't including the `lib` directory during the build process. The dependency I use (Apache Commons Codec) wasn't included, so of course it wouldn't run.
2. During the testing process, I had tried manually putting a build of Hasher into eclipse/plugins. I incorrectly assumed that if I uninstalled Hasher through the Eclipse interface, this file would be removed. It wasn't. So for the last month, I've had a stale version of Hasher being loaded into Eclipse. That's incredibly frustrating. Oh, well. Lesson learned.

Thanks very much to everyone that offered help!

Comment: I just tested your project on Eclipse Kepler and it works fine (both in IDE and when exported). Btw, your project is missing MANIFEST.MF (needed to run/export).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see issues in your packaging. If you open the jar file via any zip software you can see lib and images folder missing. You need to add entries these folders in your build.properties file. Also you need to add the library to the class path (extra classpath entry) If you build the plugin after making these changes it should ideally work.

Comment: This finally worked! I thought I had included the lib directory, but I hadn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that you first tested your plugin in target platform with just the `IFIle` specific extension and added `IFolder` later, but the updated plugin wasn't loaded to Eclipse because you didn't increase the version of the plugin and didn't run it with *-clean* (either is needed for Eclipse to reload your plugin).

Comment: This is certainly an interesting idea! I'm going to try this ASAP.

Comment: Ok, I finally had a chance to try running Eclipse with `-clean`, and that didn't fix it. There's something else going on here.

Answer (score 1):

You code is assuming that the values in the `ExecutionEvent` remain valid until your thread runs which may not be the case. Get everything you need out of the event in the `execute` method and pass them to the worker thread.

Also rather than use `object instanceof IFile` or `IFolder` use:

```
IFile file = (IFile)Platform.getAdapterManager().getAdapter(object, IFile.class);
```

and same for `IFolder`.

Comment: I just tried this, but it unfortunately didn't fix it (you can see the changes at https://github.com/gfairchild/eclipse-hasher/commit/c7743bca832a8635c61bc1d7c80b3fec2151ee65).

Comment: Ok, I fixed that issue as well (commit https://github.com/gfairchild/eclipse-hasher/commit/65cdc8296c31f39d3cd450b621a43a74a48dae98). However, it's still not working! This is just so bizarre. Why would it work for files but not for folders?

Answer (score 0):

Your question: "My question is this: how can I debug this?"

My answer: "Remote debugging"

You might want to google about that topic, but I encourage you to read the following [blog entry](http://goo.gl/0YwlW4), which I always suggest when somebody ask me about how to debug code in the first eclipse installation. Doing that, you could debug your code just in case something were different in the enviroment between your first eclipse installation and the second eclipse instance you are probably using to debug (they could be different depending on your target platform setup and your second instance launch configuration).

note: If your specific issue is a thread related issue as greg pointed out, debugging your code in the first instance installation would be useless, though.